# Why does this code return an array of undefined values along with the other values?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am mapping an array and using a switch statement to console.log some strings. It logs all of the strings but also an array: `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`. I'm not sure why it logs the array of undefined values. Is it because map returns a new array of values and in this case I am removing the values from the existing array and transforming them to strings?

```js
const arr = ['joe', 'paul', 'chris']

const statements = arr.map((name) => {
  console.log(name + ' console!')
  switch (name) {
    case 'joe':
      console.log(name + ' is cool!');
      break;
    case 'paul':
      console.log(name + ' smells!');
      break
    case 'chris':
      console.log(name + ' is cheap!')
      break;
  }
})

console.log(statements);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map` takes in an array and returns a new array, composed of calling the callback function on each item of the original array. Your callback function is not returning anything, so the `statements` array evaluates to `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`.

`.map` is not appropriate here, because you don't need a mapped array. Use `forEach` instead, and omit the `statements` variable:

```js
const arr = ['joe', 'paul', 'chris']

arr.forEach((name) => {
  console.log(name + ' console!')
  switch (name) {
    case 'joe':
      console.log(name + ' is cool!');
      break;
    case 'paul':
      console.log(name + ' smells!');
      break
    case 'chris':
      console.log(name + ' is cheap!')
      break;
  }
})
```

You could also consider avoiding `switch` entirely, since it's unnecessarily verbose and can be error-prone - use an object instead:

```js
const arr = ['joe', 'paul', 'chris']

const nameStrs = {
  joe: 'is cool',
  paul: 'smells',
  chris: 'is cheap'
};
arr.forEach((name) => {
  console.log(`${name} ${nameStrs[name]}`);
})
```

If you *did* want to construct an array of responses for each item in the array, then use `.map` and return the value at the end of the callback, in addition to logging the value:

```js
const arr = ['joe', 'paul', 'chris'];

const nameStrs = {
  joe: 'is cool',
  paul: 'smells',
  chris: 'is cheap'
};
const statements = arr.map((name) => {
  const statement = `${name} ${nameStrs[name]}`;
  console.log(statement);
  return statement;
});
console.log(statements);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not returning anything from the callback passed to `map()`. If you want to return array with `is cool,...` values `return` it in the end of function.

```js
const arr = ['joe', 'paul', 'chris']

const statements = arr.map((name) => {
  let res;
  switch (name) {
    case 'joe':
      res = name + ' is cool!';
      break;
    case 'paul':
      res = name + ' smells!'
      break;
    case 'chris':
      res = name + ' is cheap!';
      break;
  }
  console.log(res);
  return res;
})

console.log(statements);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything from the function, so the last line logs an array of undefined elements constructed by the map function's callback.

Answer (score 0):

You are logging the string instead of returning the values. [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) expects a return value like:

```js
const arr = ['joe', 'paul', 'chris']

const statements = arr.map((name) => {
  switch (name) {
    case 'joe':
      return name + ' is cool!';
    case 'paul':
      return name + ' smells!';
    case 'chris':
      return name + ' is cheap!';
  }
})

console.log(statements);
```

Comment: You can remove `break;` i guess because you are using `return`